# for loop grid row numbering

Tags: c#, css-grid, blazor

I have a Data grid of 8 columns by 97 Rows i want to number the rows from 0 to 23 every 4th row in column 0 with a for loop

i want to replace my hard coding of the numbers.

```
    <div style="grid-row:2;grid-column:1;text-align:right;font-weight:bold">0</div>
    <div style="grid-row:3;grid-column:1;text-align:right;font-weight:bold"></div>
    <div style="grid-row:4;grid-column:1;text-align:right;font-weight:bold"></div>
    <div style="grid-row:5;grid-column:1;text-align:right;font-weight:bold"></div>
    <div style="grid-row:6;grid-column:1;text-align:right;font-weight:bold">1</div>
    <div style="grid-row:7;grid-column:1;text-align:right;font-weight:bold"></div>
    <div style="grid-row:8;grid-column:1;text-align:right;font-weight:bold"></div>
    <div style="grid-row:9;grid-column:1;text-align:right;font-weight:bold"></div>
    <div style="grid-row:10;grid-column:1;text-align:right;font-weight:bold">2</div>
    <div style="grid-row:11;grid-column:1;text-align:right;font-weight:bold"></div>
    <div style="grid-row:12;grid-column:1;text-align:right;font-weight:bold"></div>
    <div style="grid-row:13;grid-column:1;text-align:right;font-weight:bold"></div>
    <div style="grid-row:14;grid-column:1;text-align:right;font-weight:bold">3</div>
    <div style="grid-row:15;grid-column:1;text-align:right;font-weight:bold"></div>
    <div style="grid-row:16;grid-column:1;text-align:right;font-weight:bold"></div>
    <div style="grid-row:17;grid-column:1;text-align:right;font-weight:bold"></div>
    <div style="grid-row:18;grid-column:1;text-align:right;font-weight:bold">4</div>
    <div style="grid-row:19;grid-column:1;text-align:right;font-weight:bold"></div>
    <div style="grid-row:20;grid-column:1;text-align:right;font-weight:bold"></div>
    <div style="grid-row:21;grid-column:1;text-align:right;font-weight:bold"></div>
    <div style="grid-row:22;grid-column:1;text-align:right;font-weight:bold">5</div>
```

and so on

Comment: Welcome to SO (StackOveflow) , please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @Luuk what's wrong with the question though? topic starter provided his current hard-coded implementation, pointed out the problem, described desired implementation. Title is clear, tags are agreeable. Not that bad for the first question.

Comment: @yolosora: tags are C#, blazor and css-grid, i don't see `C#` code where this static HTML-code is used.

Comment: @Luuk obviously c# code will be used for implemenation since it's blazor

Comment: Also the "Show what you’ve tried and tell us what you found (on this site or elsewhere) and why it didn’t meet your needs. You can get better answers when you provide research" is missing. ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask))

Comment: @Luuk the actual implementation is trivial and problem is simple, there is no reason to include any non-working oneliners since it wont improve the question.

Comment: @yolosora can you answer the question with the given information? I personally have no idea where to start! should I explain how to write a loop? or how to dynamically add blazer rows? or is it about parsing a string?

Comment: I'm sorry if the question is wrong I'm new to programming I just wanted a cleaner way to do this and don't really know how it is html but I want to replace it with a C# loop or to be more accurate my supervisor said that would be the best way but I can't ask him as he is otherwise engaged any advise to help you help me will be appreciated

Comment: @Bizhan I have no idea how this loop should look as the one found on google puts everything in the first row

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you code in Razor, the code looks like this:

```
@{
    var j = 0;
}

@for (var i = 0; i < 97; i++)
{
    <div style="grid-row:@(i+2);grid-column:1;text-align:right;font-weight:bold">
        @if (i % 4 == 0)
        {
            @(j++)
        }
    </div>
}
```

Output Preview:
[image]